# Parameter set as null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, onclick

I have this button.

```
<button type="button" 
        style="color:cornflowerblue" 
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#InsertRecord" 
        onclick="getDetail(10)">Add</button>
```

and this is my getDetail code block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getDetail(id) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetDetailContent',
            data: "{id: " + id + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (result) {
                var arry = result.split('~');

                var Type = arry[0];
                var Recipient = arry[1];
                var Status = arry[2];
                var RecipientType = arry[3];

                $("#Type").val(Type);
                $("#Recipient").val(Recipient);
                $("#Status").val(Status);
                $("#RecipientType").val(RecipientType);

            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

But when I click the button id parameter set as 0. Whats the problem here?

[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy23f.png)

Comment: I'd start with basic debugging. Add `console.log(id)` or better yet, use the debugger and set a breakpoint at the top of the function and see what is being passed. You'll find it's probably and `Event` object.

Comment: Your `data` is invalid JSON.  The "id" property name must be in double quotes. Instead of building it as a string like that, do this: `data: JSON.stringify({ id })`

Comment: it pass zero idd @HereticMonkey

Comment: it didnt solve it. still set as 0 @Pointy

Comment: My parameter....do you mean the controller parameter or the param `id` above in the javascript function?

Comment: @JamesS can you check the ss below in my question?

Comment: You should use the browser "Network" developer tool to examine what is actually being passed to your server.

Comment: Can I suggest you only include the *relevant* code.  If your `getDetail(id)` is 0 then the ajax code is *irrelevant* and will only get your comments/answers based on *that* code.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the code, *as provided*, up to the point of the error in the screenshot.  https://jsfiddle.net/0aw5t6mL/ As you can see, it works fine., so the onus is on you to provide code that *doesn't work* (or, more specifically does what you describe).   See [mcve].   Perhaps your button definition is different from what you've provided (maybe using a variable for the id and that variable isn't set).

Comment: @Mert: It appears that you are making more assumptions than observations.  The screen shot provided shows an odd mix of client-side and server-side debugging.  Since your assertion is that the problem is entirely client-side, focus only on the client-side debugging.  Use your browser's debugging tools, not the Visual Studio IDE.  Currently nobody is able to replicate the problem you describe by using *your exact code*, so you'll need to provide some demonstration of the claim you're making rather than just continuing to assert that it must be failing in the way you think.

Answer (score -1):

```js
 function getDetail(id) {

        console.log(id);
        output.innerHTML = id;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" style="color:cornflowerblue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#InsertRecord" onclick="getDetail(10)">Add</button>

<span id="output"><span>
```

Your code does function here correctly

I think your error might happen else where, Like maybe in the backend.
I am guessing due to the limited information available you are using something
like asp.net mvc/core. It could be that your Function in the backend accepts get and not POST.

But nothing can be said for sure without anymore context please edit your question to incorporate more information about the backend and where exactly the variable is NULL.

UPDATE:

Your new information in the form of a screenshot is still insufficient i recommend debugging the javascript within your browser.

Also there is no context of what endContent is and where the variable is located.

Please be more clear. This question is currently of no value.

Comment: I added an ss in my question below. Can you please check it?

Comment: @Mert did you click "Run code snippet" in the answer above?